# Is there a built-in method to pad a string?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to add zero-padding to a number.  I did some searching and can't find an obvious way to do this.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything, there's a big lack of formatting functions right now. I think the best you can do is something like:

```dart
String intToString(int i, {int pad: 0}) {
  var str = i.toString();
  var paddingToAdd = pad - str.length;
  return (paddingToAdd > 0) 
      ? "${new List.filled(paddingToAdd, '0').join('')}$i" : str;
}
```

Obviously something that took a format string would be much nicer. Feature request?

Comment: Definitely warrants a feature request :)  Ideally, something that could be included within an interpolated string.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the String function .padLeft(Int width, [String = ' '])

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_padLeft

```dart
int i = 2;
print(i.toString().padLeft(2, "0"));
```

result: 02

Answer (score 17):

*Dart 1.3* introduced a [String.padLeft](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_padLeft) and a [String.padRight](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_padRight) you can use :

```dart
String intToString(int i, {int pad 0}) => i.toString().padLeft(pad, '0');
```